# How should the OneDrive children@odata.nextLink parameter be used

Tags: api, rest, onedrive

When I open a folder, and request its children, I get back a paging variable - children@odata.nextLink.  If I call this (office 365 business) I just get the first 200 child items again.  Is this broken or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. I've opened an issue in the API issues list: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/422.

In the mean time, you can work around this bug by targeting the folder's `/children` collection directly, instead of using `?expand=children`.

For example:

```
GET /_api/v2.0/drive/root:/PathToFolderWithLotsOfFiles:/children
```

You can then page through the items in the folder as you would expect, using `@odata.nextLink`.